# Twisted triple wires when current is balanced

Tags: power-supply, cables, wire

Twisted pair cables are supposed to be effective for differential signals since the current flow is equal and opposite. If I have three wires such that the total current is also zero (say, +5V, GND, -5V), is twisting similarly effective to attenuate noise coupling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is. If the current sum is zero, then generated magnetic fields cancells out in turn it doesn't produce noise to outer world. We can say that the inductance is small, therefore it can't magnetize the environment, but also it is reciprocal, the noise from the environment can't induce a voltage in the wires.